# Highchart with many Y scales with the same value

Tags: highcharts

We are using highcharts to build line chart, but we notice the following strange behavior :
When a data contains "Y" with constante value, the chart is displing Y axis with many scales with the same value (the same value passed in data)

Is this behavior is a bug in highcharts ? how can we do to avoid it ?

Thanks in advance.

~Mounir

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or at least some code that replicates your problem?  I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response. You can try with any line chart with "Y" constante value. I made an exemple in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vqZz2/2/

Comment: For anyone following this, here's a fiddle that actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/vqZz2/4/.  @mboukayoua, I still don't understand.  Highcharts seems to be plotting what I'd expect it to do.  I straight line with a datapoint for every value you've given.  The yaxis is autoscaled with a min/max of the integers between your constant.

Comment: What do you mean with "with many scales"? Maybe you can create an image containing what you want to achieve.

Comment: -I think i can reproduce the bug in highcharts verion 2.2.1 (that we are using) and the version 2.2.4 : http://jsfiddle.net/w6JZS/
(using : <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.2.4/highcharts.js"></script>)

-But in the last stable version of highchart, it seems that it's working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/w6JZS/1/
(using : <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think i can reproduce the bug in highcharts verion 2.2.1 (that we are using) and the version 2.2.4 (see my comment above for jsfiddle code)
- But in the last stable version of highchart, it seems that it's working fine

Comment: I advice to use the newest release.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am advincing too to my team... :) thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean yAxis, so you can use min/max values or use tickPositoner / tickPositions. All of options are documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.reversed